# Contact Delegate missing

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to make a new level for my app. I am honestly just copy and pasting my code from the view controllers and gamescenes to other files that I changed the name of. Yes, I did change the names INSIDE the files too so It'll match the new level. However, my contact delegate won't work on my new level now. How can I fix this?

```
Cannot assign value of type 'Level1' to type 'SKPhysicsContactDelegate?'
```

What am I doing wrong? I just checked my main file that I had before creating a new level and it now has errors. I have't changed any of the coding.

```
    import SpriteKit
    import GameplayKit

    class Level1: SKScene {

        var ball = SKSpriteNode()
        var danger1 = SKSpriteNode()
        var danger2 = SKSpriteNode()
        var goal = SKSpriteNode()


        over

ride func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
        ball = self.childNode(withName: "ball") as! SKSpriteNode
        danger1 = self.childNode(withName: "danger1") as! SKSpriteNode
        danger2 = self.childNode(withName: "danger2") as! SKSpriteNode
        goal = self.childNode(withName: "goal") as! SKSpriteNode

        let border = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
        border.friction = 0
        border.restitution = 0

        danger1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: danger1.size)
        danger1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.dangerCategory
        danger1.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

        danger2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: danger2.size)
        danger2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.dangerCategory
        danger2.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

        ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.size.width/2)
        ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.ballCategory
        ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.dangerCategory | PhysicsCategories.goalCategory
        ball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategories.none
        ball.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        ball.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false

        goal.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: goal.size)
        goal.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.goalCategory
        goal.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false


        setupPhysics()
        startGame()
    }
    func setupPhysics() {
        physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 0.0)
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    }


    func startGame() {
        ball.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 550)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            ball.position.x = location.x
            ball.position.y = location.y

        }
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        // Called before each frame is rendered
    }
}

extension GameScene: SKPhysicsContactDelegate {



    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

        if contactMask == PhysicsCategories.ballCategory | PhysicsCategories.dangerCategory {
            print("Contact")
        } else if contactMask == PhysicsCategories.ballCategory | PhysicsCategories.goalCategory {
            print("goal contact")
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating extension of `GameScene`, create extension of `Level1`

```
extension Level1: SKPhysicsContactDelegate
```

Comment: @Schmob did it help? I'm glad. You can accept my answer. :-)